# removing sleep() from concurrent Java semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am doing a project which requires us to take the sleeping barber Java code [Here](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kerola/rio/ohjeet/Java/semaphores/s06e-huhtamaki-merikanto-nevalainen/SleepingBarber.java) and remake it into a hotel. There are several rules, but I'm having trouble with three similiar ones:

2. A thread may not use sleeping as a means of coordination
3. Busy waiting (polling) is not allowed
4. Each thread should only print its own activities

How do I go about removing the sleep methods, and what do I replace them with?

I have come up with these semaphores:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.*;

public class Hotel extends Thread {

 public static Semaphore deskClerk = new Semaphore(0, false); //semaphore representing the deskClerk
 public static Semaphore guestList = new Semaphore(0);       //semaphore representing the guests.
 public static Semaphore bellHop = new Semaphore(0, false); //semaphore representing the bellHop.
 public static Semaphore accessSeats = new Semaphore(1);   //the seats that the guestList sit down on upon entering the hotel
 int roomCounter = 0; // supposed to be an incrementing global variable integer that increments with each customer acquisition by the front desk employee
 int guestID, bellhopID, clerkID;

 // the number of chairs in this hotel is 15. 
 public static final int CHAIRS = 15;

 public static int numberOfFreeSeats = CHAIRS;
```

And these classes:

Guest

```
 class Guest extends Thread {
  //  we create the integer iD which is a unique ID number for every guest and a boolean notServed which is used in the Guest waiting loop
  int iD;
  boolean notServed = true;
  int baggage;

  // Guest Constructor
  public Guest(int name, Hotel h) {
   iD = name;
   guestID = iD;
   Random rn = new Random();
   baggage = rn.nextInt(6);
   //need a random number from 0-5. Represents number of bags.
  }

  public int getBaggage() {
      return baggage;
  }

  public boolean checkBaggage() {
      if(this.getBaggage() > 2) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  public void run() {
   while (notServed) { // as long as the customer has not been served
    try {
     accessSeats.acquire(); // tries to get access to the hotel chairs
     if (numberOfFreeSeats > 0) { // if there are any free seats
      System.out.println("Guest " + this.iD + " has entered hotel with " + this.getBaggage() + " bags");
      numberOfFreeSeats--; // sitting down on a chair
      guestList.release(); // notify the front desk salesmen that there is a customer
      accessSeats.release(); // don't need to lock the chairs
            // anymore
      try {
          roomCounter++;
          deskClerk.acquire(); // now it's this guestList turn
            // but we have to wait if the deskClerk is busy
          notServed = false; // the guest will now leave after they are served.
          this.get_Served(); // Serving the guests
          if (this.checkBaggage() == true){
              bellHop.release();
              System.out.println("Guest " + this.iD + " requests help with bags");
              //from here, need a way for the bellhop to signal the guest that they should tip the bellhop, receive the bags, and retire.
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Guest " + this.iD + " enters room #" + roomCounter + " and retires for the evening");
          }
      }
      catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      }
     } 
     else { // there are no free seats
      System.out.println("There are no free seats. Guest " + this.iD + " has left the hotel.");
      accessSeats.release(); // release the lock on the seats
      notServed = false; // the customer will leave since there are no spots in the queue left.
     }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
   }
  }

  /* this method simulates a front desk employee processing a guest */
  public void get_Served() {
   System.out.println("Guest " + this.iD
     + " receives room key for room " + roomCounter + " from front desk employee " + clerkID);
   try {
    deskClerk.release();
   }
   finally{
   }
  }
```

Clerk

```
     /* THE CLERK THREAD */

 class Clerk extends Thread {
     boolean busy = false;
  public Clerk(int name, boolean bus) {
      clerkID = name;
      busy = bus;
  }

  // this method will simulate booking rooms 
 public void serve() {
  System.out.println("Front desk employee " + this.getId() + " registers guest " + guestID + " and assigns room " + roomCounter);
  try {
   sleep(3000);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  }
 }

  public void run() {
   while (true) { // runs in an infinite loop
    try  {
     guestList.acquire(); // tries to acquire a customer - if none is available he goes to sleep
     accessSeats.acquire(); // at this time he has been awaken -> want to modify the number of available seats
     numberOfFreeSeats++; // one chair gets free
     deskClerk.release(); // the clerk is ready to serve the customer
     accessSeats.release(); // we don't need the lock on the hotel chairs     anymore
     this.serve(); // serving the customer
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex)  {
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Bellhop

```
     /*THE BELLHOP THREAD */
 class bellHop extends Thread { 
     boolean busy = false;
  public bellHop(int name, boolean f) {
      bellhopID = name;
      busy = f;
  }

  public void handleBaggage() {
      if(bellHop.availablePermits() != 0){
       System.out.println("Bellhop " + this.getId() + " receives bags from guest " + guestID);
       System.out.println("Bellhop " + this.getId() + " delivers bags to guest " + guestID);

       try {
           bellHop.acquire();
       } 
       catch (InterruptedException ex){
           System.out.println( this.getId() + " Cannot handle baggage");
       }
      }
  }

  public void run() {
   while (true) { // runs in an infinite loop
    try {
    this.handleBaggage(); // take baggage up to guests room and receive a tip
    sleep(100);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Main & hotel run()

```
    // main method 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("Simulation Starts");
     Hotel hotel = new Hotel(); // Creates a new hotel
     Clerk george = hotel.new Clerk(1, false);  System.out.println("Front desk employee " + george.getId() + " created");
     Clerk greg = hotel.new Clerk(2, false); System.out.println("Front desk employee " + greg.getId() + " created");
     bellHop bill = hotel.new bellHop(1, false); System.out.println("Bellhop " + bill.getId() + " created"); 
     bellHop bob = hotel.new bellHop(2, false); System.out.println("Bellhop " + bob.getId() + " created"); 
     hotel.start(); // begins the simulation
     greg.start();
     george.start();
     bill.start();
     bob.start();
 }

 public void run() {
     Hotel h = new Hotel();

    // This method creates 25 new guests
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        Guest aGuest = new Guest(i, h);
        aGuest.start();
        try {
            sleep(3000);
        }   
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {         
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework.

Comment: @Isaac: homework questions are not automatically off topic. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping means wasting time (or, more specifically, wasting a thread). The thread does nothing until the given time has elapsed (or the thread is interrupted).

Typically you don't want to *waste time* -- you just want to *wait* for something else to happen. For example, the clerk doesn't want to sleep when there are no guests: instead the clerk should wait for a signal that a guest has arrived, and then immediately be available to service that guest. If you were using monitor locks in Java, the clerk would `wait()` on the monitor until another thread `notify()`ed it.

`Semaphore` can be used to build the right kind of concurrency construct, but it isn't ideally suited to this kind of problem. For the general problem of "client (guest) threads each want to acquire resources (rooms) from a central mediator (clerk)" I would actually use a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to represent the "waiting in line" state and the corresponding value. Of course, that may not be the technique your professor is trying to teach you with this assignment. :-)

In the barber example you showed, and also in your code, you're also using sleeps to *simulate* work that you're not actually doing -- for example, the barber doesn't *actually* cut any hair, just sleeps for a few seconds to simulate the haircut taking some time. It sounds like that's allowed by this assignment. In a real-world system, though, you wouldn't need a sleep, it's just that the actual work the thread is doing would take a nontrivial amount of time.

Comment: Thank you! So I need to add a system of wait() and notify() to each of the classes, inside of the try blocks?

Comment: @Ash: The key is to understand *which threads need to wait*, and *what they are waiting for*. If a thread is waiting, then it means some other thread either is now doing or will in the future do something that will allow the thread to stop waiting. That *something* is what you need to identify, and then you need to signal the waiting thread when that something happens. There are lots of ways to do this, and it's not clear from your question what the best possible solution is (as I said above, I would actually use `Future`s if I was coding this myself).